# TypeScript – TypeError: Alice_1.Alice is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, testing, constructor, typeerror

I've got a file `alice.ts` with the implementation of a class called `Alice` and an interface called `IAlice`:

```
export interface IAlice {
    readonly prop: number;
}

export class Alice {
    static fromJSON(json:string) {
        const par = ...
        return new Alice(par);
    }

    readonly prop: IAlice;

    constructor(prop: IAlice) {
        this.prop = prop;
    }
}
```

In my test when I run:

```
import { Alice, IAlice } from "filepath";
...
const alice: Alice = new Alice(object);
...
```

I got as output an error:

```
TypeError: alice_1.Alice is not a constructor
```

Does anybody have an idea why this error is raised?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your declaration:

```
const alice: new Alice(object);
// Should be:
const alice = new Alice(object);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've simplified the code for consistency purpose, and it's when the typo appeared. I've edited the question.